# Suitescript issue returning columns[0] error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Im trying to prepare a search in suitescript and im getting an error message simply stating columns[0]

Im trying to extract all user notes that are part related to the customer ID that is passed in, the fields are present in the saved search in the UI, but when I try to access it via code with the code below, i cant seem to filter them on the criteria for the customer ID that is entered.

any assistance greatly appreciated

below is my code

```
    var filt = new Array();
    filt.push( new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid','customer','anyOf',_customerID)   );

var cols = new Array();
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('name'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('author'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('title'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('memo'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('direction'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('type'));
    cols.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('company'));
        var userNotes = nlapiSearchRecord('note','customsearch_pm_user_note_search',null,filt,cols);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra null in this line

```
nlapiSearchRecord('note','customsearch_pm_user_note_search',null,filt,cols);
```

Correct usage is `nlapiSearchRecord(<recordtype>,<searchid>,<filters>,<columns>)`